# Jackson 2 and Spring Autowired bean

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I've encountered a problem with Jackson serialization for my User object.
There are a few private fields with getters and setters. And everything works fine when I do something like this:

```
public String json() {
   MyUser user = new MyUser();
   user.setUsername("myName");

   return mapper.writeValueAsString(user); // Valid JSON
}
```

But i'd like to autowire User object with Spring Framework:

```
@Autowired
private MyUser user;

public String json() {
    System.out.println(user.getUsername()); // Property set before and it works
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(user); // Error
}
```

And this doesn't work. I've got an error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.piggymetrics.classes.PiggyUser$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5f23855e["targetSource"]->org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource["beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["parentBeanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["beanClassLoader"]->org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader["resources"]->org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot["context"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext["logger"]->org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog["logger"]->java.util.logging.Logger["parent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["handlers"]->org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler["formatter"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:59)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:26)
```

And when i try to ignore these unknown errors

```
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
```

I got an Infinite recursion:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve["container"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine["pipeline"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline["basic"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve["container"]
...
```

Looks like Spring did something wrong with autowired MyUser instance so Jackson can't serialize it.

Is there a way to fix it?

UPDATE

MyUser class is pretty simple:

```
package com.metrics.classes;

import com.metrics.classes.interfaces.User;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyUser implements User {

    private String username;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your user contains a field which has a reference to the user ?

Comment: Please share your `MyUser` class

Comment: I've updated my question whit MyUser class. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use `MyUser` as a Spring managed bean, Spring wraps your object into a proxy - so when you are calling `mapper.writeValueAsString(user);` you are actually passing a proxy as argument. Said proxy contains some properties, that mapper cannot serialize.

You can try applying filter before serialization to include only the properties you need:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleFilterProvider simpleFilterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider()
    .addFilter("myUser", simpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("username"));

mapper.setFilters(filterProvider);
return mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
```

Comment: But, what if i have 20 fields in MyUser class? And these fields might be modified later. Is there another way to serialize Autowired POJO?

Comment: @silent-box there might be pther ways - but I haven't yet encountered such a scenario so I cannot be sure. There might be ways that will tell mapper to treat passed object as it's superclass - i.e. `MyUser`, or some `@Json...` annotation with similar meaning.

Comment: Ок. Спасибо еще раз :)

Comment: @silent-box не за что)

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown in `UnknownSerializer` class. Here is the exact code which throws the exception:

```
throw new JsonMappingException("No serializer found for class "+value.getClass().getName()
   +" and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer 
   (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )");
```

The error message appends the name of the class which it is not able to serialize. In your case, based on the error message the problem is with `org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter` class. Hence, there is no problem with `MyUser` class.

Now coming to reason for this error, it is thrown when serializing an entity that has all fields private. In `org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter` class all fields are private without any public getter and setter methods.

Comment: I think its pretty clear from his description that his fields have public getters and setters.