# Unable to create REST response using @Proxy and Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I've encountered a problem with Jackson serialization for my LoginResp object. 
It shows me

```
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.util.logging.LogManager["systemContext"]->java.util.logging.SystemLoggerContext["namedLoggers"]->java.util.Hashtable["global"]->java.util.logging.LoggerWeakRef["referent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["manager"]->java.util.logging.LogManager["systemContext"]->java.util.logging.SystemLoggerContext["namedLoggers"]->java.util.Hashtable["global"]->java.util.logging.LoggerWeakRef["referent"]->java.util.logging.Logger["manager"]->java.util.logging.LogManager["systemContext"]->java.util.logging.SystemLoggerContext["namedLoggers"]->java.util.Hashtable["global"]->java.util.logging.LoggerWeakRef["referent"]-.....
```

I'm trying to replicate the same scenario and using the same code , as mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371835/jackson-2-and-spring-autowired-bean). But getting the above error. Please help, as I simply wants to write the value of my "resp" bean, to my "someJsonString" variable. Thanks in advance.

These are my dependencies

```
<properties>
    <servlet-api-version>3.1.0</servlet-api-version>
    <spring-webmvc-version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring-webmvc-version>
    <jackson-version>2.6.4</jackson-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-webmvc-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My LoginResp class

```
package my.beans.resp;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class LoginResp {

private String username;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

}
```

My REST controller

```
package my.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;

import my.beans.req.LoginReqB;
import my.beans.resp.LoginResp;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/login")
public class LoginC {

@Autowired
private LoginResp resp;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String authenticateUserLogin(@RequestBody LoginReqB request) {

    resp.setUsername("abc");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
    SimpleFilterProvider filterP = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("loginResp",
            SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("username"));
    mapper.setFilterProvider(filterP);

    String someJsonString = "";
    try {
        someJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(resp);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return someJsonString;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

Observation: Jackson is not able to convert/process a proxy object at line

`someJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(resp);` in try block.

Solution: As proxy objects are wrapped around the actual object. I'm accessing the actual object behind the proxy using the function mentioned [here](http://www.techper.net/2009/06/05/how-to-acess-target-object-behind-a-spring-proxy/).

Effect: Now, no need to customize my ObjectMapper, i.e.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
SimpleFilterProvider filterP = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("loginResp",
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("username"));
mapper.setFilterProvider(filterP);
```

is no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use System.out.println method on the server side. Always use some logging utility such as log4j slf4j or any other one you might know. However, this is very unlikely a reason for your problem. Judging by the error, you have some circular reference with your logging configuration.Set a break point in your controller to see if you get there before the error occurs or the error occurs even before you attempt to invoke your method. In any case my guess is that you have logging configuration problem and your problem is the result of that and not of your code, which seems to be OK at first glance except System.out.println usage.

Comment: Thnks for your input and you are right. My error is cominn inside try block on line "someJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(resp);"

Comment: I'm not using any explicit logger, but the moment I use @Scope, my Jackson shows this error for "java.util.logging". As you can c..i'm using everything from "mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);" , "mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY)" and also a custom filter... But no effect

Comment: try to remove the line "mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);" and "System.out.println(e.getMessage());"

Comment: Jst now tried. Now its showing " "Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve["container"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine["pipeline"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline["basic"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve["container"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine["pipeline"]->org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline["basic"]"    "

Comment: set a break point on line "someJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(resp);" and see what you get there.

Comment: Showing "username=null".  But dont know why?

Comment: remove your filterprovider and repeat

Comment: Same.. "username=null"...no luck

Comment: Also you shouldn't hold your private LoginResp resp; as a member variable you should instantiate it every time in your authenticateUserLogin method with "LoginResp resp = new LoginResp()", but I don't think it is your problem, your serialization doesn't work and I am not sure why

Comment: In debugging...even after using resp.setUsername method...its still showing "username=null". I will have to dig dipper but thanks for your promptness and suggestions. Really appreciate it.